Problem regarding the intersection of 2 cyclic subgroups
I was working through a question regarding the intersection of 2 generators and believe I am misunderstanding.
Let a be an element of a group. Suppose that |a| = n. Find the generator of <a^x>intersection<a^y>. (say x < y)
Doesn't the notation <a^n> indicate <a^0, a^1, a^2, ..., a^n>? If this is the case then with the above, and if a is the same element, would it not be <a^0, a^1, ..., a^x> and <a^0, a^1, ..., a^x, ..., a^y>, hence the intersection would just be <a^0, a^1, ..., a^x> and generator would be <a^x> since these elements are in both sets?
I know that if a group is cyclic and has a generator <a^n> then
<a^0, a^1, a^2, ..., a^n> is the whole group.
I also know that the cardinality of an element in this situation is when it equals the identity (e.g |a| = w, a^w = e). But based on my current logic this does not even seem relevant information for the question at hand.
Could someone illuminate this?

$<a^n>={a^n, a^{2n},a^{3n},…}$

Better formatting:  $\langle a\rangle$ using \langle a \rangle

@J.W.Tanner that is what I was missing. Thank you.

You're welcome.  Here is a MathJax tutorial


Doesn't the notation $\langle a^n\rangle$ indicate $\langle a^0, a^1, a^2, ..., a^n\rangle$?

No, the notation $\langle a^x\rangle$ indicates $\langle a^x, a^{2x}, a^{3x} , ...\rangle $, which may or may not be the entire group, depending on whether $x$ and the order of the group are relatively prime.
The notation $\langle a\rangle$ indicates $\langle a, a^2, a^3, ..., a^n\rangle$.  There's no sense including $a^0$ and $a^n$ separately, since they are both the same (identity) element if the order of $a$ is $n$.
